# "You use an obsolete definition of (?) hat". What must stand in place of (?)?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What must stand in place of  (?) in the sentence

"You use an obsolete definition of (?) hat"

Is it the definite article? Indefinite? Nothing? Or does it depend on the context?

Comment: You use an obsolete definition of "hat".

Comment: Or "You use an obsolete definition of *hat*."

Answer (score 2):

In your example sentence

> You use an obsolete definition of *hat*

No article is necessary since you are using "hat" as the word itself not the object worn on one's head.

> You use an obsolete definition of *a* hat.

would mean you are referring the the definition of the thing worn on your head.

You might have written

> You use and obsolete definition of *the* word hat.

which has the same meaning as your original sentence and clearly refers to the *word* hat.